# How do I consolidate this two column table?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do this in Excel

Here is my data, two columns:

```
Affectionate    5 
Affectionate    8  
Affectionate    3 
Affectionate    2  
Affectionate    1
Angry6   
Angry5
Angry4  
Angry2
Angry1
```

How do I get it to appear in Excel so that it's

```
Affection   Angry                
5           6
8           5 
3           4
2           2
1           1
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Result]

You can use relative pointing.

The numbers on the left are in the column **C**, the number on the right are on column **F**.
The formula for numbers on the right is $C1,$C2,$C3 etc. The **$** sign indicates **Absolute** pointing, so they'll always point to column **C**, while the number isn't preceded by the $ so it will be relative. So the first number will take the value from row 1, the second from row 2 etc.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Basically, the first column is the category.  I am trying to transform it to that the first row will display the category, and each row under the category will display the corresponding value from the second column in the first table.

Comment: Do you already have those columns in Excel and do you just want to make them appear as below?

Comment: My left column is full of categories like "affectionate" and "angry".  I was just wondering if there's a faster way to convert everything, instead of doing it individually for all the categories.

Comment: Oh, I see, I don't think there's a way to make it faster.